# How to fetch device location from action-on-google

Tags: node.js, dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I'm using nodejs as a webhook for fetching the current location of user but constantly getting that error `Webhook call failed. Error: 500 Internal Server Error` in dialogflow response, here some screen shots.
Thank you.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dk3dJ.png)

Comment: Try [this](https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/helpers#place_and_location)

Comment: Please don't post screen shots of code. They make it very difficult to read and diagnose your problem. Instead, edit your code to include the source as text directly. (See https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code) If you have error messages, seeing the full error logs can also really help (from your webhook as well as from the simulator if you're using that). It can also help to indicate at what point you're getting that error message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your code, there are a number of things going on which could be causing issues. It isn't clear which one is actually causing the problem.

First, your use of libraries. It looks like you're trying to import the version 1 libraries for both the Action SDK and the (legacy) ApiAi interface, but not using them. If you are using the latest version of actions-on-google (you don't show your package.json), these will fail.

You also seem to be trying to use `DEVICE_PRECISE_LOCATION`, but this isn't defined anywhere. Although this mirrors the name of a permission, this variable doesn't automatically get populated.

While this isn't causing the error, it also looks like you're doing this as part of the welcome intent, but in order to get the location, you must [explicitly request permission to get the location](https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/helpers#user_information) from Google.